# Rendering an iCal .ics file using Django: fixing incorrect newlines

Tags: python, django, icalendar

I'm using Django's `render_to_response` to create an .ics file on the fly for people to download. The raw content of this .ics file is fine, and validates when I use [this tool](http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/). However, when I upload the file that is generated, I get this error:

> Your calendar is using an invalid newline format. Make sure to use \r\n to end lines rather than just \n (RFC 2445 §4.1).

Is there any way to get `render_to_response` to generate this page with `\r\n` as newlines, instead of just `\n`? I've got the feeling that this will probably be some low-level Python setting, that I can't easily override in Django.

Sensible alternative solutions also considered! Thanks.

Comment: render_to_response [is a shortcut for Template.render(Context)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context). If you called Template.render yourself, it would return a string. So you could then call string.replace('\n', '\r\n'), right? Seems too easy, maybe I am missing something.

Comment: That seems to work perfectly, do you want to post it as the answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render_to_response` is a shortcut for `Template.render(Context)`. If you called `Template.render` yourself, it would return a string. So you could then call `string.replace('\n', '\r\n')`.