# Django and ICS Files

Tags: django, icalendar

I want to give the users of my website the chance to export/download small ics files for events. I understand that you can use the vObject library to automatically create ics files but for the time being lets just assume they are all manually written and stored in my static files directory.

1) How would I return these files in a view?
2) How would I then render a small icon representing this? How would I call each ics file in the template?

I'm new to Django so go easy. In addition to the docs I've read [this](http://blog.thescoop.org/archives/2007/07/31/django-ical-and-vobject/) but it skips the details and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177865/rendering-an-ical-ics-file-using-django-fixing-incorrect-newlines) but again doesn't deal with the fundementals.

I think I'd have to put a MIMEType arguement into the render_to_response() shortcut in the view - perhaps something like

```
response = render_to_response(events.html, mimetype='text/calendar')
```

But from there on I'm stuck? Anyone kind enough to shed any light?

Added: In the Django Book chapter 11 is always uses HttpResponse instead of render_to_response() in the examples... But render_to_response can still take a mimetype arguement so there isn't an issue here right?

Added 2: If the ics files aren't created when the view is called I'm guessing this would make it pretty difficult to call static files when rendering pages of events dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are static files, you merely put them with the rest of your static files and have your webserver deliver them like any other static file. Django shouldn't be involved in the process at all.

**EDIT**

The problem here is that this is all theoretical since you haven't actually made a choice about whether these will actually static files or dynamically created by Django, and the that choice vastly changes implementation strategies.

If you are going to use static files. Then, the most obvious way to handle this is to treat them as file uploads on your events, i.e. you add a `FileField` for your ICS, and then attach the static file when you create the event. Then, as you're looping through your events or whatever, you make your ICS link's href just: `{{ event.my_ics_field.url }}`. But, there again, the files will then be stored in your `MEDIA_ROOT` directory, which will be served by your webserver, not Django.

*Or*, you could set up some sort of naming scheme (such as ID of event) for your ICS files and store them one of your app's static directories or some other directory that you add to `STATICFILES_DIRS`. Then, you compose the URL in your template like `/path/to/ics/files/{{ event.pk }}.ics`. It's a little more fragile this way, and the end result is the same: your webserver handles the files and Django couldn't care less.

However, if you're going to do this dynamically, Django will need to be involved in actually serving the files since it will be involved in creating them. You simply create a view that will create the ICS file and make sure Django returns the response with the appropriate mimetype. You then just hook it up to a urlpattern (which would include something like the event's ID or slug so the view would know what event to create the ICS for) and just reference that urlpattern in your template the normal way, with `{% url %}`.

Comment: Don't think it will be as easy as that if lists of events are dynamically rendered? and used on more than one page?

Comment: Thanks! Adding them to the model makes the most sense in my circumstances I think

Comment: Finally got it to work now I've worked around the MEDIA_URL settings etc. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've done it in the past. I have a model for Files, which has path, file_name, and download_name fields. In this case, f represents the File object from my database. This is code in the view for downloading file f:

```
def DownloadFile(request, fid):
    f = File.objects.get(id=fid)
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(f.download_name)
    response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str(f.path + f.file_name)
```

For the icon, you could have a gif, ics.gif in your static files folder, which would represent all ICS files, I would include the file's download name so the user can see which file to download. In the template these would be links, something like:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .download{ cursor: pointer; border: none; }
</style>
.
.
.
{% for file in file_list %}
    <a href="/download/{{ file.id }}" target="_blank">
        <img src="/static/ics.gif" class="download" />
        {{ file.name }}
    </a>
    <br />
{% endfor %}
```

Of course, this is if you store file details in a model. Also, you need to make an entry in urls.py to handle `url(r'^download/(?P<fid>\d+)$', 'views.DownloadFile')`. I'm not sure how you're getting your list of files, but this is how I would handle them.

Comment: Makes sense. Nice I'll give it a blast now thanks. And the fid will be say the event primary key, which will also be the id of the calender file?